How do I build a static linked version of NumPy?
Because I've embedded a static linked version of Python (so it can be shipped as a single executable) I lose the ability to use Python extension modules such as NumPy. How can I build a static linked version of NumPy for my static interpreter or include it as a builtin extension into the static library?
The library even if installed cannot be found or loaded:
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace py::literals;

QString MAppContext::test()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::dict locals = py::dict("name"_a="World", "number"_a=42);
    py::exec(R"(
        import sys
        message = ""
        try:
            import numpy as np
            message = s.to_string()
        except ModuleNotFoundError as moduleErr:
            message = "[Error]: Failed to import (Module Not Found) {}.".format(moduleErr.args[0])
        except ImportError as impErr:
            message = "[Error]: Failed to import (Import Error) {}.".format(impErr.args[0])
        except Exception as e:
            message = 'An exception occurred: {}'.format(e)
    )", py::globals(), locals);

    auto message = locals["message"].cast<std::string>();
    return QString::fromStdString(message);
}

The message returned is:

Module not found.


Is your goal to statically link numpy and Python, or to produce a single executable which contains all extensions? The latter is much easier, and can be done through PyInstaller or py2exe.

@NickODell yes the goal is to produce a single executable which dont require python to be installed on the PC that will run it. As you probably noticed my application is build with c++ and Qt using pybind11 as a wrapper to the Python C API. How can i use pyinstaller in this scenario? As far as I know pyinstaller creates an exe of it's own from a python script but in my case I have a whole c++ and Qt application that calls "embedded" (literally const char strings in the c++ code) python scripts.

For embedding Python, I don't know of a solution, but you could switch from embedding to extending python (https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) which would be easier.

@NickODell oh the embedding part is already done, I can run arbitrary python code from my application without the need to have python installed in the machine that is running the application the problem arise when i want to use a module that is an "extension library" (pyd) in that case even if I install it and ship it with the application the library is not found or loaded, every other module that is a "normal" (only python code with no "extension library" dependency) works just fine.
